# Are questions about the use of IDEs appropriate to post on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, reopen-closed

Looking at [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355868/disabling-copy-of-blank-text-in-sql-server-management-studio), there are multiple close votes and I agree to an extent, but if this sort of question can't be asked on Stack Overflow, where else would it be asked?

The main reason that I think it should stay is that the target audience on Stack Overflow will have a significantly higher ratio of developers who would both relate to the question and have found ways to overcome it.

This is also specifically about a tool that again a considerable number of members would be highly experienced in, and as such are likely to have an answer.

So, while it is not specifically a *code* related issue, surely questions directly about the IDE and other text editors commonly used by programmers could still be welcomed on Stack Overflow, after all this is a quite frequent problem encountered in everyday programming by programmers.

Comment: This question is now closed as off topic, but the wording of that close type contradicts this specific use. surely a question about programming, not general computing has some place on SO, OP even posted minimal steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks @JeanneDark That sums it up for me, I guess this then is a dupe now ;)

Comment: Questions about a *programming* IDE are on topic.  So not SMSS, it is an end-user tool.  It resembles Visual Studio a great deal, merely because they used the shell version of VS.  It doesn't become on topic because the pixels look the same.  Consider recommending [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssms).

Comment: Isn't there a higher-voted duplicate? This comes up on a regular basis.

Comment: Clearly there's a deleted explanation or two missing from the comments here, but since when is SQL Server Management Studio not a developer tool? I honestly can't see how SSMS isn't a ["software tool commonly used by programmers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); I can't say I've ever seen it used outside a developmental/ programming context.

Comment: @HansPassant SMSS is by no means an end-user tool, I dare you to let your end users in there on your production applications. For this reason it is viable in SuperUser but I also agree that posting in DBA is equally applicable to OP, however OP was most likely expecting to interact with they're developer peers as this issue is closely related to common application coder's processes, so I would still post in SO rather than bother DBA's with something this trivial.